# 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r, function, arguments

Here's a prop.test function:

```
baby.prop.test = function (x, n, p, conf.level = 0.95) {
  # ...
  return(prop.test(x,n,p,conf.level))
  #baby.prop.test$statistic
}
# test case
baby.prop = baby.prop.test(72, 100, .7, conf.level=.99)
stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(as.numeric(baby.prop$statistic), .43643578)))
stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(as.numeric(baby.prop$p.value), .66252058)))
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in match.arg(alternative) : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `formals(prop.test)` or `?prop.test` the fourth argument is called `alternative` and has to be a character of `c("two.sided", "less", "greater")`. Your fourth element is `conf.level` (which is the fifth of `prop.test`, the order matters). To "ignore" the order of arguments you have to name your arguments (at least the `conf.level`):

```
prop.test(x, n, p, conf.level=conf.level)
```